# How to match column name instead of its values in Conditional Statement to calculate a new column

Tags: join, pivot, union, tableau-api, crosstab

I have a dataset, where I have several measures/variables.  These variables are stored in different columns with names describing their values.
For my data analysis, I have added these variable-names (measure names) in rows so that I have arranged my cross-tab view in columns based on values of another variable in my data set.
My problem is that I want to add one extra dummy column (variable) where values are static/fixed but depend on variable names instead of their values.

[image: Sample input and output]

It may be clear from above that I want to add some `IF THEN ELSE END` like condition which is dependent on column/variable name instead of its values.  Please note that my dataset has four table joins and I need to use Measure Names in creating a Goal calculation. How may I proceed?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in a little more detail, by including sample input and desired output?

Comment: @AnilGoyal I have added samples

Comment: I have edited question and answer both, see that if it helps. Please upvote if it served your purpose.

Comment: Thanks @AnilGoyal. Dummy column is my request. But the below solution does not solve my use case because i am joining four tables in the dashboard and [Pivot Field names] is actually [Measure name] and i am not able to use that in Goal calculated field.

Comment: Also please show me screenshots of both `data source` pane/tab and your viz

Comment: So, Is your problem solved by `UNION` ?

Comment: @AnilGoyal In my attempt to give a sample, I made the problem much simpler. Each data source has different metrics so union is not a practical solution. I have decided to use a simple solution where I change the alias name for the measure name column in worksheet to goals at the right side of the same column. It is not being shown as a separate column as required but this serves the purpose for now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the most basic view to build in tableau.  Do it like this screenshot

[image]

Right click Grand Total field and select 'average' instead of 'sum' and you're done.

**EDIT:  May be your problem is to add additional dummy column.  In that case, proceed like this..**

Click both measure field and pivot them in 'data' tab to get your data transformed like this..

[image]

Create a calculated field Goals like this

[image]

and you can create a view like this

[image]